# Difference between int16 and int32

Tags: vb.net

Please help me to understand difference between int16 and int32 using below example:

```
Public Class ABC
    Public Function Test(ByVal x As Int16, ByVal y As Int16) As Double
        Return x * y
    End Function

    Public Function Test(ByVal x As Int32, ByVal y As Int32) As Integer
        Return x + y
    End Function
End Class
```

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim obj As New ABC
        MsgBox(obj.Test(10, 20))
    End Sub
End Module
```

In this case the Method `Test` with parameters `int32` is getting called.
As per definition both the 10 and 20 are following in the range of both data types. So why `obj.Test(10, 20)` is not calling `Test` method with `int16` parameter?

Comment: Constant integer values are Int32 by default. You should cast the constant value as Int16 to call the Int16 overload method.

Comment: Better yet, use the [`S` literal type specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx).

Answer (score -2):

Their storage capacity is different.

Int 16 -- (-32,768 to +32,767)

Int 32 -- (-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647)

Comment: This literally answers "what is the difference between int16 and int32," but it has nothing to do with the question which is about overload selection.